# How to fix this code function to compile and install this component into Delphi 10.2?

Tags: delphi

I get this error:

> [dcc32 Warning] xcalndr3.pas(733): W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'ShortString'

I am coming from Delphi 2010 where this worked without a problem.  I am a beginner.

```
function TXBaseCalendar.GetCellText(ACol, ARow: Integer):string;
const
  LongDayNameArray: ARRAY[1..7] OF STRING[9]= 
                                             ('Sunday',
                                              'Monday',                                                 
                                              'Tuesday'
                                              'Wednesday',
                                              'Thursday',
                                              'Friday',
                                              'Saturday');
var
  DayNum: Integer;
begin
  if ARow = 0 then    { day names at tops of columns }
  begin
    if FUseShortDayNames Then
      Result := ShortDayNames[(StartOfWeek + ACol) mod 7 + 1]
    else
      Result := LongDayNameArray[(StartOfWeek + ACol) mod 7 + 1];
  end
  else 
  begin
    DayNum := FMonthOffset + ACol + (ARow - 1) * 7;
    if (DayNum < 1) or (DayNum > DaysThisMonth) then Result := ''
    else Result := IntToStr(DayNum);
  end;
end;

{ SelectCell override - returns false for cells that shouldn't be selected }
function TXBaseCalendar.SelectCell(ACol, ARow: Longint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := inherited SelectCell(ACol, ARow);
  if ((not FUpdating) and FReadOnly) or (CellText[ACol, ARow] = '') then
    Result := False;
  if FBlockWeekends and ((ACol = 0) or (ACol = 6)) then
    Result := False; 
end;

{ SetCalendarDate - property access method to set calendar focused date }
procedure TXBaseCalendar.SetCalendarDate(Value: TDateTime);
begin
  if Value <> FDate then
  begin
    FDate := Value;
    UpdateCalendar;
  end;
end;
```

If I leave out the `ShortDayNames` array and the `LongDayNameArray`, I can build, compile, and install this into my VCL components.

Please be kind, as I am not a professional nor a trained programmer.

Comment: People who want Delphi to progress and build its user base shouldn't be voting down questions from new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is a WARNING, not an ERROR. It will not prevent you from compiling and installing your component.

You are declaring an array of `ShortString` values, not an array of `String` values.

`ShortString` is a `string` type that has an explicit length specified at compile-time, ie `String[9]`.

`ShortString` uses 8-bit `AnsiChar` characters, same as `AnsiString`, but is limited to 255 characters max.

`String` is an alias for `AnsiString` prior to Delphi 2009, but is now an alias for `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009 onward, where `UnicodeString` uses 16-bit `WideChar` characters.

See [String Types](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) in Delphi's documentation.

Assigning a `(Unicode)String` to a `ShortString` requires a data conversion at runtime, and that conversion is lossy for non-ASCII characters `> #127`.  That is what the compiler is warning you about.  In your particular example, you are using ASCII characters, so you will not experience any data loss at runtime, but the compiler is not validating the actual characters, it is only looking at the string types.

Simply change your array to use `String` instead of `String[9]`, especially since you are converting the `ShortString` values to `String` anyway when assigning them to the function's `Result`.

```
const
  LongDayNameArray: array[1..7] of String = 
                                             ('Sunday',
                                              'Monday',                                                 
                                              'Tuesday'
                                              'Wednesday',
                                              'Thursday',
                                              'Friday',
                                              'Saturday');
```

There is rarely a good reason to ever use `ShortString` in modern Delphi coding.

And BTW, you claim that your original code worked in Delphi 2010. `UnicodeString` was added in Delphi 2009. So, everything I described above applies to Delphi 2010 just as  it does to Delphi 10.2.

Comment: What you haven't pointed out (although it is in the link) is that specifying a string length (`string[9]`) means that the compiler uses the `ShortString` type.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment I think that was made pretty obvious, but OK, I've pointed it out explicitly now.